# Which file I have to include in order to use browserify

Tags: browserify

I want to use a module that uses require. 
I have installed browserify with node for that reason. 
My problem is that I can't find which javascript file I have 
to include in my html page in order to use browseriry.

Answer (score 1):

Typically Browserify is run as a step in your build process, and outputs a .js file that contains all the required modules. You would then add that in your web page. This means you should be running Browserify from the command line (or Grunt or Gulp if you use one of those tools) to build the JavaScript file to be deployed.

The "Hello World" example on the [Browserify home page](http://browserify.org/) walks through these steps. In their example they run the command

```
browserify main.js -o bundle.js
```

to process the `main.js` file, find all required modules, and bundle them together into `bundle.js`.

The web page would then only need to include `bundle.js`

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```